# Correct listener for Jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery autocomplete API , I am trying to get the value from a textbox after it is select . Which listener should I be using to get the value from the textbox . I tried .focus but it only works after the textbox is clicked again. I need this event to be triggered when the value from the drop down is selected (as opposed to the search words typed in the textbox)

Comment: could you please show the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, maybe you need to bind to the close event of autocomplete widget.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"],
    close: function (event, ui) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/6mLJs/)**

Comment: Also how would I send this piece of data as a GET request using Ajax?

Comment: Well that's a totally different question, if that answers your questions could you please mark it as answered. Thanks.